# Objects slips from gripper during Gazebo simulation

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, gazebo, rviz, ros-noetic

I'm trying to simulate a simple scenario of pick and place for my UR5 ARM robot but i'm encoutering some problems during grasp. In particular, when grasping the gripper starts shaking untill the object slips out of the gripper the gripper seems to explode as can be seen in [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15gNWtedMupI_NI720OvKaif2TLRaGd7T/view?usp=sharing) I am using effort_controllers. please help me to solve the issue

MY GAZEBO PLUGINS:

```
<gazebo>
        <!-- loading plugin: mimic joints works in gazebo now -->
         <plugin name="gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin_1" filename="libroboticsgroup_gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin.so">
                    <joint>gripper_finger1_joint</joint>
                    <mimicJoint>gripper_finger2_joint</mimicJoint>
                    <multiplier>1.0</multiplier>
                    <offset>0.0</offset>
                    <sensitiveness>0.0</sensitiveness>
                    <maxEffort>500</maxEffort>
                    <robotNamespace>/ur5</robotNamespace>
 </plugin>
        <plugin name="gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin_2" filename="libroboticsgroup_gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin.so">
                    <joint>gripper_finger1_joint</joint>
                    <mimicJoint>gripper_finger2_inner_knuckle_joint</mimicJoint>
                    <multiplier>1.0</multiplier>
                    <offset>0.0</offset>
                    <sensitiveness>0.0</sensitiveness>
                    <maxEffort>500</maxEffort>
                    <robotNamespace>/ur5</robotNamespace>
 </plugin>
 <plugin name="gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin_3" filename="libroboticsgroup_gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin.so">
                    <joint>gripper_finger1_joint</joint>
                    <mimicJoint>gripper_finger1_inner_knuckle_joint</mimicJoint>
                    <multiplier>1.0</multiplier>
                    <offset>0.0</offset>
                    <sensitiveness>0.0</sensitiveness>
                    <maxEffort>500</maxEffort>
                    <robotNamespace>/ur5</robotNamespace>
 </plugin>
 <plugin name="gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin_4" filename="libroboticsgroup_gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin.so">
                    <joint>gripper_finger1_joint</joint>
                    <mimicJoint>gripper_finger1_finger_tip_joint</mimicJoint>
                    <multiplier>-1.0</multiplier>
                    <offset>0.0</offset>
                    <sensitiveness>0.0</sensitiveness>
                    <maxEffort>500</maxEffort>
                    <robotNamespace>/ur5</robotNamespace>
 </plugin>
 <plugin name="gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin_5" filename="libroboticsgroup_gazebo_mimic_joint_plugin.so">
                    <joint>gripper_finger1_joint</joint>
                    <mimicJoint>gripper_finger2_finger_tip_joint</mimicJoint>
                    <multiplier>-1.0</multiplier>
                    <offset>0.0</offset>
                    <sensitiveness>0.0</sensitiveness>
                    <maxEffort>800</maxEffort>
                    <robotNamespace>/ur5</robotNamespace>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
    <!--using the grasp plugin so that the gripper can grasp things in simulation-->
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_grasp_fix" filename="libgazebo_grasp_fix.so">
            <arm>
                <arm_name>ur5</arm_name>
                <palm_link>wrist_3_link</palm_link>
                <gripper_link>gripper_finger1_finger_tip_link</gripper_link>
                <gripper_link>gripper_finger2_finger_tip_link</gripper_link>
                <gripper_link>gripper_finger1_inner_knuckle_link</gripper_link>
                <gripper_link>gripper_finger2_inner_knuckle_link</gripper_link>
                <gripper_link>gripper_finger1_knuckle_link</gripper_link>
                <gripper_link>gripper_finger2_knuckle_link</gripper_link>
            </arm>
            <forces_angle_tolerance>100</forces_angle_tolerance>
            <update_rate>10</update_rate>
            <grip_count_threshold>4</grip_count_threshold>
            <max_grip_count>8</max_grip_count>
            <release_tolerance>0.005</release_tolerance>
            <disable_collisions_on_attach>false</disable_collisions_on_attach>
            <contact_topic>__default_topic__</contact_topic>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
```

RED BOX IN WORLD FILE :

```
 <model name='unit_box_red'>
      <link name='link'>
        <inertial>
          <mass>1</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.166667</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.166667</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.166667</izz>
          </inertia>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        </inertial>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <gravity>1</gravity>
        <visual name='visual'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.06393 0.060568 0.060433</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
            <shader type='pixel'>
              <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
            </shader>
            <ambient>1 0 0 0</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
            <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
          </material>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
          <transparency>0</transparency>
          <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
        </visual>
        <collision name='collision'>
          <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.06393 0.060568 0.060433</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>0.1</mu>
                <mu2>0.1</mu2>
                <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
                <slip1>0</slip1>
                <slip2>0</slip2>
              </ode>
              <torsional>
                <coefficient>1</coefficient>
                <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
                <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
                <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
                <ode>
                  <slip>0</slip>
                </ode>
              </torsional>
            </friction>
            <bounce>
              <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
              <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
            </bounce>
            <contact>
              <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
              <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
              <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
              <ode>
                <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
                <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
                <kp>1e+13</kp>
                <kd>1</kd>
                <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
                <min_depth>0</min_depth>
              </ode>
              <bullet>
                <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
                <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
                <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
                <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
                <kp>1e+13</kp>
                <kd>1</kd>
              </bullet>
            </contact>
          </surface>
        </collision>
      </link>
      <static>0</static>
      <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
      <pose>-0.553128 -0.37896 0 0 -0 0</pose>
    </model>
```